# How to launch user's default mail client, default window(inbox)

Tags: android, email, android-intent

Well I want to redirect user from app to default mail client in his phone. 
I heard that i can't just make intent that launch mailing app. So the general idea is to get possible applications for Intent.Action_Send, and just start one that user picked with Intent.CreateChooser(...);.

But it seems that i can't or i don't know how to get picked package name.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

So i made quick woraround for my problem. 
I'm letting user decide if to run gmail, on ConversationList, or open email client by himself. 
I also protected it from crashing when there will be no gmail client on some phone.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it is possible to launch the Mail client per Intent:

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.email/.activity.EmailActivity");
startActivity( LaunchIntent );
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: 03-16 14:33:52.614: E/AndroidRuntime(13179): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 14:33:52.614: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1374)
03-16 14:33:52.614: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
03-16 14:33:52.614: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)

Comment: Which phone are you using? It may occur that your local Mail client has another packagename. You can look that up with the tag "ActivityManager" in logcat. The app catlog in the Play Store supports that filter, too.

Comment: Im using Xperia x10, but im trying to get it work on any phone. Even if user use other client that gmail. Is there a way to list mail client's packages in app. I though that if i use CreateChooser, i will be able to print user choice package name, and just launch it. (basically i can use CreateChooser to open app for sending email, and i want to get into inbox)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        .....
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("text/html");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "some subject");
        .....
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
        .....
```

It swows Dialog with posible email clients. After user choose some, it redirect him to choosen client....

Comment: to composer window. So it will not satisfy me. I need to get into inbox.