# Android - Receive notifications and launch POP3 email client from my app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, pop3

I'm creating a simple Android app and I wish to have an associated widget that displays new message notifications from my POP3 email client (configured on my device). Then when the user taps the widget, the app launches (even just to the inbox is fine).

1. Is this possible?
2. What is the intent for this?

I have read on other posts that its possible to do with the gmail app but haven't found any that directly state POP3 will work.

***UPDATE***
As stated in comments I'm wondering if its possible to create my own "mail server" that will give me notifications and then when a user taps the button in my app it will just boot the set "default" mail client.

Can any one foresee issues with such a setup?

Comment: When you asked the developers of your unnamed "POP3 email client" these questions, what did they tell you? Did they point you to their API documentation?

Comment: Well I was initially thinking the built in "email" app that came on my Nexus for example... I see your point though if every client is different it would be hard to know. Unless there is a way to access only the "default" client?

Comment: There isn't a "default" client per se. Moreover, there is nothing in the Android SDK for what you seek. If you are referring to the AOSP Email app, it too does not offer any sort of API to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: ok... Do you have any suggestions / workarounds that could achieve a similar result.. i would be ok with booting the browser to access the inbox but I would still need the 'new message' notifications.

Comment: I would focus on finding an email client you like that either has this feature, has an API for you to implement this feature, or is open source so that you could work with them to contribute this feature. Beyond that, I have no advice.

Comment: Yes I see that [K9- Mail](https://github.com/k9mail) is a very good open source client. It might be possible to use that code to get the notification functionality... I see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737934/how-to-launch-users-default-mail-client-default-windowinbox) that it is possible to launch the default client... seems like a lot of work but could be worth it :-)